# Listview Filter not working with SearchView, How to Update the listview with filter?

Tags: android, listview, filtering, searchview

this is my 3rd Question in stackoverflow since I don't know how to use stackoverflow. My question is about my project for my paper. Please help me...
I have 1 listview and 1 SearchView. I want to add Search filter to my Listview, my problem is :

1. I Have some item displaying in ListView
2. For Example, in 1st list I have data "Aisyah" and in next list I have data "Farhan" order by name, When I type "FA" the ListView displaying "Farhan" at the top of ListView.
3. But when I click, the selection is made for "Aisyah"(First Item in ListView) not For "Farhan"

Basically, the positions of the data in the list view is not getting refreshed after we have performed search. But I don't know how to Refresh the ListView and get correct positions of the data.

Please Help Me... I stucked in this for several days.
This is my code..

```
public class DosenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
//root url dari webservice
public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://fyptes.esy.es/";
//deklarasi varibel untuk mengirim data ke activity lain
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String NAMA = "nama";
public static final String SITUS = "situs";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";
public static final String TELEPON = "telepon";
public static final String KANTOR = "kantor";
public static final String JABATAN = "jabatan";
public static final String MATKUL = "matkul";
public static final String FOTO = "foto";
//listview untuk menampilkan data
private ListView listview;
//varibel books bertipe List dan List tersebut berdasarkan objek Listdosen
private List<Listdosen> dosens;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dosen);
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    //inisialisasi listview
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDosen);

    //memanggil method untuk mengambil data dosen
    getDosen();

    //setting onItemClickListener untuk listview
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}

private void getDosen() {
    //Ketika Aplikasi mengambil data kita akan melihat progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Mengambil Data","Mohon tunggu..",false,false);
    //Logging Interceptor
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    //set Level Log
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())//GsonConverter untuk parsing json
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();

    RestAPI service = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);

    Call<Model> call = service.loadListDosen();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {  //Asyncronous Request
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            List<Listdosen> dosen = response.body().getListdosen();

            //memasukkan data dari varibel dosen ke dosens
            dosens = dosen;
            //memanggil method untuk menampilkan list
            showList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

private void showList() {
    //String array untuk menyimpan nama semua nama dosen
    String[] items = new String[dosens.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < dosens.size(); i++) {
        items[i] = dosens.get(i).getNama();
    }
    //Membuat Array Adapter for listview
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_dosen_listview, items);

    //setting adapter untuk listview
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
}

//method ini akan dieksekusi ketikan listitem diklik
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //membuat intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DosenDetailActivity.class);
    //mengambil dosen dari list
    Listdosen listdosen = dosens.get(position);
    //menambahkan detail dosen untuk intent
    intent.putExtra(ID, listdosen.getId());
    intent.putExtra(NAMA, listdosen.getNama());
    intent.putExtra(SITUS, listdosen.getSitus());
    intent.putExtra(EMAIL, listdosen.getEmail());
    intent.putExtra(TELEPON, listdosen.getTelepon());
    intent.putExtra(KANTOR, listdosen.getKantor());
    intent.putExtra(JABATAN, listdosen.getJabatan());
    intent.putExtra(MATKUL, listdosen.getMatkul());
    intent.putExtra(FOTO, listdosen.getFoto());

    //memulai activity lain untuk menampilkan detail dosen
    startActivity(intent);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // this is your adapter that will be filtered
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText))
    {
        listview.clearTextFilter();
    }
    else
    {
        listview.setFilterText(newText.toString());
    }

    return true;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this some time ago, however, it worked without `searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));`

Comment: you are getting selected as "Aisyah" because after searching you are updating the list view .Look at my answer I have posted complete code for this issue.

Comment: I just deleted 
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()‌​));
but still not working for me...

Comment: @ParsaniaHardik How to use that code for searchview? sorry for ask many question...

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to search names and again populate the list view according to search query.It is working fine for me.

```
 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textlength = edittext.getText().length();
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                //  arrayList2 = arraylist;

                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {

                    username[i] = arraylist.get(i).get("Username");
                    Log.d("unm", username[i]);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                    if (textlength <= username[0].length()) {


                        if (username[i].toLowerCase().contains(
                                edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                            arrayList2.add(arraylist.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList2);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);


            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: But I use SearchView not edittext, how can I use that?

Comment: well I dont know about SearchView but if you can use EditText instead SearchView this will work best for you

Comment: and one thing that above code has arraylist with hashmap so change it according to your need

Comment: my code don't have arraylist with hashmap, any idea?

Comment: you are using string array to populate listview so replace arraylist with string array..